# 80-openshift-network.conf is missing in /etc/cni/net.d

Tags: ansible, openshift, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise, cni

I'm having problem deploying a cluster in Openshift. Any reason why?

Version

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo),
oc version: oc v3.11.43

ansible 2.6.18
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

openshift-ansible-3.11.43-1.git.0.fa69a02.el7.noarch
```

Command: ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts playbooks/deploy_cluster.yml

I tried:

- 80-openshift-network.conf (copying this from a working openshift env to the current env I'm having problem)
- Adding NM_CONTROLLED=yes, PEERDNS=yes in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192
- Re-installing from scratch

I also tried this one from https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/10969

And still failing.

If this can help, you can check my post on github https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/11825

My Inventory file (/etc/ansible/hosts):

```
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nfs
etcd
nodes
new_nodes

[OSEv3:vars]
template_service_broker_install=false
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=None
ansible_ssh_user=root
openshift_master_cluster_hostname=None
openshift_deployment_type=openshift-enterprise
os_firewall_use_firewalld=True
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]
openshift_master_default_subdomain=cloudapps.10.110.25.147.nip.io
openshift_disable_check=memory_availability,disk_availability,package_version,docker_image_availability,package_availability,package_update,docker_storage

oreg_url=10.110.25.141:8082/openshift3/ose-${component}:${version}
openshift_examples_modify_imagestreams=true
openshift_image_tag=v3.11.43
openshift_pkg_version=-3.11.43

openshift_additional_registry_credentials=[{'host':'10.110.25.141:8082','user':'admin','password':'admin123','test_login':'False', 'tls_verify':'False'}]

[masters]
cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph  openshift_public_ip=10.110.25.147 openshift_ip=10.110.25.147 openshift_public_hostname=cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph openshift_hostname=cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph ansible_connection=local

[nfs]
cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph  openshift_public_ip=10.110.25.147 openshift_ip=10.110.25.147 openshift_public_hostname=cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph openshift_hostname=cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph ansible_connection=local

[etcd]
cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph  openshift_public_ip=10.110.25.147 openshift_ip=10.110.25.147 openshift_public_hostname=cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph openshift_hostname=cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph ansible_connection=local

[nodes]
cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph openshift_public_ip=10.110.25.147 openshift_ip=10.110.25.147 openshift_public_hostname=cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph openshift_hostname=cssbh001d.openshift.smart.ph openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra'}" openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master-infra' openshift_schedulable=True ansible_connection=local

[new_nodes]
```

Expected: 
Successfully deployed cluster using this command: ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts playbooks/deploy_cluster.yml

Actual Results:

```
TASK [openshift_cluster_monitoring_operator : Wait for the ServiceMonitor CRD to be created] ********************************************************************************************
Tuesday 13 August 2019 17:00:34 +0800 (0:00:02.250) 0:14:45.437 ********
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for the ServiceMonitor CRD to be created (30 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for the ServiceMonitor CRD to be created (29 retries left).
.......
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for the ServiceMonitor CRD to be created (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for the ServiceMonitor CRD to be created (1 retries left).
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm also experiencing the same issue.